how to implement sending one message in a telegram bot on telegraf.js
Tell me why the newsletter does not work for my bot users?
All users are recorded in bd with their id
const { Telegraf, Markup, Scenes, session } = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
const db = require("./database/db-pool");

what I'm trying to do is pull each user from the database and send him a message using the /sendAd command
bot.command('sendAd', async (ctx) => {
    try {
        const conn = await db.getConnection();
        const [rows] = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM users');
        conn.release();
        for (const row of rows) {
            console.log(`Sending a message to a user chatId: ${row.chatId}`);
            await ctx.telegram.sendMessage(row.chatId, 'Your advertising message is here');
        }

        ctx.reply('Advertising sent to all users');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        ctx.reply('There was an error sending the ad.');
    }
});

please help me

Just there's a block before the command which is gulping all text messages..
bot.on('text', async (ctx) => {
    if (ctx.session.complainStep === 'waiting_for_complaint') 

..
like so
